# Get ASP.NET development server port number

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to get asp.net development server port number in C# method. can you help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get it from Request:

```
Request.Url.Port
```

And this is not strictly port of Development web server, this is a port of currently used web server.

Comment: How would you get the corresponding SSL port programatically? (I believe it's called `IISExpressSSLPort` in the configuration file). I want to redirect locally to HTTPS

Comment: Well in the context of this answer you can get https port with Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PORT_SECURE"] but only if current request is a ssl request. You must query IIS for SSL port for Site, I believe that you can do that with Microsoft.Web.Administration assembly, look at the Site.Bindings, and then find binding for SSL. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.binding.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396