# Get the port the request to a locally run ASP.NET app came in on?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, port

This is strictly for debugging purposes of an ASP.NET Web Role when running locally.  I have an MVC 5 ASP.NET app that returns a link from one of the Controller methods.  The link requests a specific item from a database.  For example:

(link without http protocol prefix so SO doesn't complain)

```
*localhost/Customers/GetCustomer/3*
```

This gets customer # from the database.  The problem is the link is not valid when I am running IIS Express when designing the Web Role on my local machine, before it is published to the server.  Since IIS Express listens on a specific port, the link needs the port number to be usable by the local web site calling the Web Role method.  It should be:

```
*localhost:3876/Customers/GetCustomer/3*
```

Is there any way to determine that port from my ASP.NET Controller that servers up the link?    Something from the Controller Request property perhaps?  Otherwise I'll be stuck with a conditional compilation symbol and I'd like to avoid that because then I have worry about setting that back to the production value before publishing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10347798/456814), you can use the following:

```
int port = Request.Url.Port
```

[`Request.Url`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.url(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a `Uri` object, which has a [`Port`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.port(v=vs.110).aspx) property.